# How to assign myself priviliges?

Tags: custom-object

I click on an object in my Tabs and get *Insufficient Priviliges...You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.*

I am an admin in my sandbox.  How can I give myself rights to see this object?

Edit: The list view of that object overridden with a VF page.  The page is real simple:

```
<apex:page >
  <apex:enhancedList type="rf_Proposal__c" height="300" rowsPerPage="10"
      id="ProposalList" customizable="False" listId="00BM0000000syQK" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a System Administrator, there is no reason why you wouldn't be able to see a record. Are you positive that your user account has the System Administrator profile? The only thing that I could think of here is that there is some custom permissions structure enforced on a Visualforce page. Is the view of that object overridden with a VF page?

EDIT: In your object view override, it looks like you're attempting to use an enhanced list based on a list view that no longer exists.

Comment: Unless I am missing something completely obvious.  http://i.imgur.com/Cd2aiAn.png

Comment: Yes, it is overridden with a VF page.  Does that matter given that I am an admin?  If so, how do I fix it?  Edit: And it's enabled for the profile http://i.imgur.com/STPOotf.png

Comment: Can you update your post to include the controller code and VF page that is the overridden view?

Comment: I updated the original question...plus I added every profile to the the list of enabled profiles for this page.  Still nothing.

Comment: Does the list Id being referenced still exist? To test, construct a URL like this: https://na14.salesforce.com/701?fcf=00B800000088xFk where the 701 is your object's 3 digit object prefix and the id is that list id. Also make sure that you salesforce server base URL is correct for your server pod.

Comment: Ah, you are right - I removed the reference to the listId and it worked right away.  Not sure what listId was anyway.

Comment: So the bottom line (just to be sure) is that `listId` is not required since I've already specified the `type` attribute?